# Not able show hidden span

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying too show a hidden span which has a opacity of 0.6 and this is my code:

```
    <span  class="changePicture" id="changePicture"><h3 class="SolidBlack">Change Pictue</h3></span>
```

Css:

```
 .changePicture{
            background-color:azure;
            margin-left: -248px;
                height: 70px;
            width:246px;
            opacity: 0.6;
              position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
            color: aliceblue;
            margin-top: 30px;
             padding-left: 30px;
  }
        .SolidBlack{
            font-weight: bold;
    color: #000000;
            opacity: 1;
        }
```

Script:

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
$("#changePicture").hide();

     $(".edit").click(function(){

       $("#changePicture").show(1000);


     });
  });
```

I am able to hide the element but not show it. Can i know where i am going wrong?

Comment: in css no identification for id `changePicture`

Comment: what??? i am using class to apply style in css so that doesnt make any difference

Comment: it should be .changePicture in your CSS to start with

Comment: the problem in your js... where is edit class? no edit class at your code

Answer (score 1):

Try [this Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nywovyah/)

HTML :

```
<span class="changePicture" id="changePicture"><h3 class="SolidBlack">Change Pictue</h3></span>

<div class="edit">edit</div> <!-- Should add the edit button -->
```

JavaScript :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".changePicture").hide();

    $(".edit").click(function() {
        $(".changePicture").show(1000);
    });
});
```

CSS :

```
.changePicture {
  background-color: azure;
  margin-left: -248px;
  height: 70px;
  width: 246px;
  opacity: 0.6;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  color: aliceblue;
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.SolidBlack {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: When the page loads, it will hide the `.changePicture` and when you click on the `edit` button , it will show again ..
Are you sure it doesn't work D:

Comment: yep damn  sure check it once

Answer (score 0):

it should be .changePicture in your CSS to start with and your jQuery code also has #changePicture instead of .changePicture

Answer (score 0):

You haven't any problem in your code, it work fine but I think the problem is that you are giving the span.changePicture a large margin-left with negative value so you can't see it .

in this demo : https://jsfiddle.net/IA7medd/u5u9cura/

I just remove this margin from you style and it work fine.

```
.changePicture{
  background-color:azure;
  //margin-left: -248px;
  height: 70px;
  width:246px;
  opacity: 0.6;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  color: aliceblue;
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".changePicture").hide();

    $(".edit").click(function() {
        $(".changePicture").show(1000);
    });
});
```